# Save drawn Image in canvas at server in asp.net

Tags: jquery, c#-4.0, html5-canvas

I'm able to save image file at server but image is saving as blank image the image drawn on canvas is not saving but if i draw rectangle,circle then the image is saving fine plz help whts the problem in my code...

script code:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

         var myCanvas =  document.getElementById("Canvas1");
         var myContext = myCanvas.getContext("2d");
         var myImg = new Image();
         myImg.src = "images/cabinbg.jpg";
         myImg.onload = function () { myContext.drawImage(myImg, 0, 0); };


         var dataURL = document.getElementById("Canvas1").toDataURL("image/png");
         $('#<%=btnAdd.ClientID %>').live('click', function () {
             dataURL = dataURL.replace('data:image/png;base64,', ''); 

             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "LayoutMaster.aspx/GetImage",
                 data: "{ 'image':'" + dataURL + "'}",
                 contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                 dataType: 'json'
             }).done(function (respond) {
                 //alert(respond);
             });

         });
```

cs file

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
    public static void GetImage(string image)
    {
        if (image != "")
        {
            try
            {
                FileStream fs;
                byte[] photo = Convert.FromBase64String(image);
                fs = new FileStream(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/images/abc.png"),       FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
                BinaryWriter br = new BinaryWriter(fs);
                br.Write(photo);
                br.Flush();
                br.Close();
                fs.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.Message.ToString();
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not waiting for the image onload to finish before you try to extract the canvas content as data-url.

```
myImg.src = "images/cabinbg.jpg";
myImg.onload = function () { myContext.drawImage(myImg, 0, 0); };

//... you go right to extracting here before onload
//    above potentially has finished leaving canvas blank
//    as nothing is drawn yet...

var dataURL = document.getElementById("Canvas1").toDataURL("image/png");
```

To fix this you need to put the extrating code inside the onload event:

```
function extractImage() {
    /* here goes the canvas.toDataUrl etc.. */
}

myImg.onload = function () {
    myContext.drawImage(myImg, 0, 0);
    extractImage();
}
myImg.src = "images/cabinbg.jpg";
```

(And NOW I see you are actually chopping the data-url's header *before* uploading.. my bad..)

<strike>Assuming the data-url's actual data (string) arrives at server you seem to forget to chop of the data-url's header.</strike>

Decoding base64 including the data-url's header won't work very well.

The string would look like this (for details see [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)):

```
data:[<MIME-type>][;charset=<encoding>][;base64],<data>
```

In this case:

```
data:image/png;base64,the-base64-data...
```

So what you need to do is to parse the header and chop it off up-to and including `...;base64,`, then decode the remaining string.

Worth to mention: if you don't specify image format for `toDataUrl` [it will always be PNG](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#a-serialization-of-the-bitmap-as-a-file).

Of course, if you expect various formats you would need to implement a more in-depth parser to read mime-type, encoding and so forth.

Comment: i may be wrong, but i agree that i'm not waiting for onload function but still my image is getting displayed propery in my canvas, now here comes the problem when i upload the content of the canvas i get incomplete data. I searched more about this and i got few result that concluded that i'm uploading data of 2MB which lot more to be handled in data-url. I'm still stuck in this problem.

Comment: The image would eventually be displayed as when loaded the image is drawn to te canvas. The problem is in the mean time the content of the current canvas is extracted with or without the image (depending on if the image gets drawn fast enough to the canvas before the toDataURL is called, which is doubtful). Could be a size problem. Try to extract canvas as a JPEG instead to see if that helps in regards to transfer size. If that makes a difference then you'll know.

Comment: if i'm using image src=dataURL  the image is showing properly but when i making ajax post i saw tht dataURL content is not same as in my WebMethod parameter (GetImage(string image))